# 'Largest' open set such that given functions are diffeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. I need to find an open set $D \subseteq R^2$ which should be as large as possible such that $f$ is (still) a diffeomorphism and state $f(D)$.

$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$$

I know that $f$ is the complex square function $z \mapsto z^2$ if we identify $\mathbb R^2$ via $\mathbb C$. So $D$ cannot contain both $z$ and $-z$. So $D:=\{z \in \mathbb C:Re(z)>0\}$ should be one possible solution.

> What does $f(D)$ look like?
>
> And could you give me any tips on how to do the same for $$g(x,y)=(e^x\cos y, e^x \sin y)$$

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem with polar coordinates? In that case $f$ becomes $f(\rho,\vartheta) = (\rho^2 \cos 2\theta, \rho^2 \sin 2\theta)$. That looks like a good way to proceed with your second function as well.

Comment: I tried it but how can I conclude that $f(D)=\mathbb C \setminus \{(-\infty,0]\}$?

Answer (score 0):

$f(D)=\mathbb C \setminus \{(-\infty,0]\}$. If $u+iv \in \mathbb C \setminus \{(-\infty,0]\}$ then you can easily solve the equations $u+iv=x^{2}-y^{2}+2ixy$ and find  a solution with $x>0$. G=F or example $\sqrt {u^{2}+v^{2}}=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $x^{2}-y^{2}=u$ so we can take $x=\frac {u+\sqrt {u^{2}+v^{2}}} 2$. Note that $x>0$.

Comment: For $g(x,y)=(e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$: can I pick $D=(0,2\pi)$ and $g(D)=\mathbb C \setminus \{z \in \mathbb C: Re(z)\ge 0\}$? Because I know that $exp:\mathbb R \times [0, 2 \pi) \to \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is bijective. and if we consider the open set $(0, 2\pi)$ instead, we get rid of $\{z \in \mathbb C: Re(z)\ge 0\}$

Comment: Can you tell me if this is correct?